# Batch File - loop incrementing count in value not displaying correctly

Tags: loops, batch-file, syntax, increment

I'm trying to read a file and output the lines of data into registry keys. The data collection works, but I don't understand the syntax required to increment the string values in the last loop.

```
@echo OFF


SETLOCAL DisableDelayedExpansion
FOR /F "usebackq skip=1 delims=" %%a in (`"findstr /n ^^ C:\GetSID.txt"`) do (
set "var=%%a"
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
set "var=!var:*:=!" This removes the prefix
echo(!var:~76,63!>>C:\SIDoutput.txt
goto :EndLoop
)
:EndLoop
set /p SID= <C:\users\paintic\SIDoutput.txt

set KEY_NAME="HKEY_USERS\!SID!\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\PrinterPorts"

set Counter=1
for /f %%x in (C:\users\paintic\Networkprinters.txt) do (
  set "Line_!Counter!=%%x"
  set /a Counter+=1
  if !Counter!==3 (Echo %line_counter%)
)

set /a counter2=!counter!-3

set counter=1
```

The part below is what I can't get to work. I'm trying to write LINE_1, LINE_2 and LINE_3 values from the previous loop to increment via the loop below. So VALUENAME should equal LINE_1, TYPE should = LINE_2's value and DATA should = LINE_3 on the first run and keep going up by 1 until the loop finishes (end of the file read)

```
`for /L %%i in (1,1,%counter2%) do (

   set ValueName=%Line_!counter!%
   set /a counter+=1
   set Type=%Line_!counter!%
   set /a Counter+=1
   set Data=%Line_!counter!%
   set /a Counter+=1
   echo !ValueName!
   echo !Type!
   echo !Data!  

REG ADD %KEY_NAME% /v !ValueName! /t !Type! /d !Data! /f

)

ENDLOCAL 

Pause`
```

Comment: Please show sample data, possibly as it would appear in the `LINE_` array, and more importantly, the values you expect to derive from that data as `valuename`, `type` and `data`. What on earth do you mean by 'keep going up by 1`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On searching for errors in batch file it is always helpful to use in first line `@echo on` or remove `@echo off` or comment this line with `rem` to see what `cmd.exe` really executes.

Command line interpreter fails on lines with `set VariableName=%Line_!counter!%` as the interpreter does not know what to expand first. I think it is not possible to create dynamically the name of an environment variable and reference next the value of this environment variable. This approach most likely does not work ever.

However, what you want to achieve can be done much easier directly in second loop as the following example demonstrates:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

rem Create data for demo example.
set "KEY_NAME=HKEY_USERS\S-1-5-20\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\PrinterPorts"
echo TestValue>"%TEMP%\Networkprinters.txt"
echo REG_SZ>>"%TEMP%\Networkprinters.txt"
echo Sample Data>>"%TEMP%\Networkprinters.txt"
echo AnotherValue>>"%TEMP%\Networkprinters.txt"
echo REG_DWORD>>"%TEMP%\Networkprinters.txt"
echo ^1>>"%TEMP%\Networkprinters.txt"

rem Now the loop follows which reads the data from the file line
rem by line and build the line for using command "reg.exe" to
rem add the data to registry of the user with the defined SID.
set Counter=1
for /f "usebackq delims=" %%x in ("%TEMP%\Networkprinters.txt") do (
   if "!Counter!"=="1" (
      set "ValueName=%%x"
   ) else if "!Counter!"=="2" (
      set "ValueType=%%x"
   ) else (
      set "ValueData=%%x"
      rem Echo the command instead of really executing "reg.exe".
      echo reg.exe ADD %KEY_NAME% /v "!ValueName!" /t !ValueType! /d "!ValueData!" /f
      set Counter=0
   )
   set /a Counter+=1
)

rem Delete the text file created for demo example.
del "%TEMP%\Networkprinters.txt"
endlocal
```

This solution is much easier than what you have tried and can be maybe even more simplified.

Comment: Thanks so much Mofi! Works perfectly! Genius :)